# How to eliminate <progress> smoothing in Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I have a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0twdL27y/10/

```html
<head>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css?version=5" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>


<progress class="p1" id="test1" value="0.5"></progress>
<progress class="p2" value="0.2"></progress>

</body>
```

In Edge, you can see the progress bar smoothes between each data point.  When it fills up, it resets to zero, but that animates.  So it looks like the progress bar is decreasing.  (I only want it to fill up, reset, fill up, on and on).  I don't even want it to smooth between points.

In Chrome, it simply jumps to the point.

How can I disable that smoothing in Edge?  Or are `<progress>` bars abundantly silly and I should just switch to `<div>`?  Does Edge have some weird native interpolation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the process here, maybe my question should be deleted.  I found out that this is solved by... updating Edge (or your the PC update).

The newest version of Edge does use Chromium, and this problem goes away.